# aggregate data programmatically in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to be able to use data.table in a loop to aggregate some data. The following code works:

```
mydata = data.table(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10))
sum = list()
sum$a = mydata[, list(sum_a = sum(a))]
sum$b = mydata[, list(sum_b = sum(b))]
```

However, the code below fails:

```
sumlist = list()
for (var in c('a','b')) {
   sumlist[[var]] = mydata[, list(paste0('sum_', var) = sum(get(var)))]
}
```

I know the problem is with the contents of the call to list() inside the data.table brackets, but I'm not sure how to specify it. Most of the existing questions pertain to the assignment of new variables with ":=", for which a version of the above code does work. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming on the lhs of `=` wouldn't work.  We can use `setNames`

```
sumlist = list()
for (var in c('a','b')) {
    sumlist[[var]] = mydata[, setNames(list(sum(get(var))), paste0('sum_', var))]
 }
```

-output

```
sumlist
#$a
#       sum_a
#1: 0.0328273

#$b
#         sum_b
#1: -0.04686505
```

Comment: There is no question about data.table which akrun fails to answer. It is known.